# Paste To Match Style App Shortcut

Tags: macos, keyboard, copy-paste, shortcut

I have to copy and paste a lot of stuff and it bugs me when the formatting is copied over, In pages there's a way to paste using the destination formatting but the keyboard shortcut is 4 keys long which annoying.

[image]

Is there anyway to change the in-app shortcuts or generally just swap them around so cmd + V will paste and match the style?

I've already looking in system preferences but I can't see anything like this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

App Shortcuts defined in System Preferences → Keyboard → Shortcuts → App Shortcuts override the default shortcuts.

Therefore, you can set up the shortcuts so that Paste is ⌥⇧⌘V and Paste and Match Style is ⌘V, as this will override the standard shortcuts.

[image]

Comment: Hah! that's great, i'll accept in a few mins when it lets me, thanks